# How can I parse HTML tags and content from a string?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

For example, I have the string

```
'<p class="something">text goes here</p>'
```

I'd like to parse it out into an array of each tag and the content, ie:

```
['<p class="something">', 'text goes here', '</p>']
```

Comment: Don't use a Regular Expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: How should your program behave if there are nested elements? Or CDATA sections (with unescaped angle brackets)? Why single-out `#text` nodes and not attributes and element names?

Comment: What would you use such an array for? Sure doesn't seem very practical. An object would be more sensible

Comment: How should it handle self closing elements `br`, `img`, `input`, `hr` etc?

Comment: There will not be nested elements, I have an array of string elements with no nesting. For self closing elements it would just return the tag. For example, '<br>' or '<br />'. Thanks!

Comment: Consider [jquery's parseHtml](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) that will create DOM elements you can access, it won't give you your array but it will pretty much give you all the info you need as DOM properties.

Comment: @jon The OP didn't tag the question with JQuery and the DOM standard `.innerHTML` does this without the need for JQuery.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, yup I was being lazy, went with the first google result for "parse html with javascript". `innerHtml` is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained the use case for this, but this answer would provide the same data (organized a little differently in the array) and that data could be used to recreate the element, if needed.

```js
var test = "<p class='something'>text goes here</p>";

// Set up an element that can contain the parsed string
var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");

// Parse/load the string into the element
dummyElement.innerHTML = test;

// Now we can extract metadata about the element and populate the array
var htmlData = [];

// Shortcut to element
var el = dummyElement.firstChild;

// Push node name into array:
htmlData.push(el.nodeName);

// Loop through attributes and put them into array:
for(var x = 0; x < el.attributes.length; x++){
  htmlData.push(el.attributes[x].nodeName + "=" + el.attributes[x].nodeValue);
}

// Put element content (if it has any) into array
htmlData.push(el.textContent);

console.log(htmlData);
```

Comment: still clumsy to use when array length will vary due to number of attributes - but does answer the question

Comment: @charlietfl Even on the most involved element that uses all possible attributes, the array length is still very well in the easily processable range of a JavaScript array.

Comment: oh yeah, that's not an issue. If I was Op I would opt for an object personally, where attributes was one property( array), tagname , content etc as other props. Wasn't suggesting anything wrong with the answer. It does answer the direct question

Comment: @charlietfl Got ya. Yes, I would go about this differently as well. Wish the OP explained the use case.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the better way to solve your problem, but can help you.

```js
const elements = [
  '<p id="x" required>Content X</p>', 
  '<p id="y" class="y">Content Y</p>',
  '<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>'
];

const parser = new DOMParser();

const result = elements
.map(element => parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html"))
.map(html => html.firstElementChild.children[1].children[0])
.map(child => {
  const nodeName = child.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  const attrs = [...child.attributes]
    .map(attr => {
      if (attr.value === '') {
        return attr.name;
      } else if (attr.value.indexOf('"') > -1) {
        return `${attr.name}='${attr.value}'`;
      } else {
        return `${attr.name}="${attr.value}"`;
      }
    })
    .join(' ');
  
  return [
    `<${nodeName} ${attrs}>`, 
    child.textContent, 
    `</${nodeName}>`
  ];
});

console.log('Result', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```